# Compare two `Any`s in a switch statement if they conform to `Equatable` protocol

Tags: swift

I want to do something like this:

```
func match(firstAny: Any, _ secondAny: Any) -> Bool {
    switch (firstAny, secondAny) {
        case (let first as Equatable, second as Equatable):
            return first == second
        case (let first as AnyObject, second as AnyObject):
            return first === second
        default:
            return false
    }
}
```

But I can't have the case with `Equatable` types. How to workaround it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being `Equatable` doesn't mean that you can apply `==` to every other `Equatable`, so this can't work. `Equatable` types are can only be equated to their own type. So even if Swift could do this, your approach would be wrong. You'd need to make sure that the two types have the same `Self` (which is somewhat complicated in the presence of subclasses).

There are ways to get something similar overloads, but I've found that they're very fragile. For example:

```
func match<Eq: Equatable>(first: Eq, _ second: Eq) -> Bool {
    return first == second
}

func match(first: AnyObject, _ second: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return first === second
}

func match(first: Any, _ second: Any) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This can work in very limited cases, but if the compiler can't prove at compile time that the type is `Equatable` (and there are many cases where in theory it could prove it, but in fact it does not), then you'll call the wrong function. Debugging it is a real pain.

The answer in almost all cases is to redesign your system to not require this, usually by dealing with the types your program actually needs rather than trying to solve it for every possible type. Making thing over-generic is a common problem in Swift; you hit all the sharp edges that Swift can't actually handle. I've never seen these solutions work reliably otherwise.

(It's worth noting that if `match` could be implemented simply and without weird corner-cases, then stdlib would almost certainly implement `==` this way. The fact that `==` doesn't work that way is a strong suggestion that it is a much more complicated problem than it appears in Swift. Occasionally stdlib is just wrong, but usually it's the way it is for a reason, and if you find yourself adding an "obviously" missing piece, it probably has surprises in store. I've burned myself that way many times....)

Comment: If only one could redesign KVO.